# Transaction Control in PostgreSQL procedures without Autocommit

Tags: postgresql, procedure, autocommit

Is it possible to have transaction control(COMMIT/ROLLBACK) inside postresql procedure if auto-commit is disabled?
From below link I can understand that postgres 11 will not allow commits, if auto commit is disabled. Is this feature available in any future versions? (Postgres 12 and 13 beta)
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/99b87249-d08c-8082-340e-84273150b59e%402ndquadrant.com#74880e948075c03e3e209a60dd33af06

If transaction control is not possible without autocommit, Do we have anyway to do in postgresql?

Comment: "*Do we have anyway to do in postgresql?*" - only with autocommit enabled

Comment: Handle transactions from your client code.